# Positioning Table in Center of Page

Tags: html, css

It seems like there is a simple fix to this but I cannot figure it out, much less find an answer so I am going to ask. All I am trying to do is get the menu ".nav" centered horizontally on the page. The problem is, I want the logo on the left and it seems to be messing with me centering the nav.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/4QGL09u.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -wekit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(000, 255, 000);
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 000, 000);
}
.nav {
  width: 200px;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="top">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/adZJ4Ln.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item">Home</li>
        <li class="item">Projects</li>
        <li class="item">Images</li>
        <li class="item">More</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say table, but you have a menu. Also please search, this has been asked and answered lots of times

Comment: I have already searched for answers, and none of them applied to what I was trying to do here. They all stated "margin:auto" or similar as an answer.

Comment: It's not table it's  menu so please provide jfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dp7yetbq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this output r u expecting

check output in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/manife/edit?html,css)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/4QGL09u.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -wekit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#top {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(000, 255, 000);
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 000, 000);
}
.nav {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="top">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/adZJ4Ln.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="item">Home</li>
        <li class="item">Projects</li>
        <li class="item">Images</li>
        <li class="item">More</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked, what exactly did you do to change it? I have tried margin: 0 auto but it didn't work when I first tried.

Comment: i just removed display:table property and added margin:0 auto;

Comment: I wonder why display:table was the culprit. Well anyways, thank you for the help!